# php rabbitmq consumer reconnect

Tags: php, rabbitmq, haproxy

I have a PHP app that uses RabbitMQ.   For redundancy, I created a pair of RabbitMQ servers and joined them in a cluster.  I also have a VyOS failover cluster running HAProxy to load balance connections and to provide rerouting in case of a failover.

Yesterday, our VyOS cluster decided a failover was needed (probably a brief network interruption).  HAproxy was stopped on one VyOS the virtual IP's moved, and restarted HAproxy on the other node.

After this, I viewed the queues in Rabbit and saw there was zero consumers for each queue.  I checked the machines running the consumers still had the PHP running.   I left them for a while to see if they'd reconnect and they did not.  I had to kill the PHP script and restart them, and they re-connected and began consuming immediately.

I think that RabbitMQ and HAproxy are working as expected... Now I need the PHP consumer to support a failover event... in otherwords, instead of just hanging, it needs to detect a disconnection, and automatically reconnect.

Here is my RabbitMQ class.  Thanks for any help in advance!

```
<?php
while(true)
{
    try{getMessages("transcode2");}
    catch(Exception $e){echo($e->getMessage()."\n");}
    sleep(1);
}
require_once("../api/db.php");
require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
function sendMessage($msg,$prio)
{
    global $channel;
    $msg=json_encode($msg);
    $queue="transcode2";
    $channel->queue_declare($queue,true,false,false,false);
    $channel->basic_publish(new AMQPMessage($msg,array('priority' => $prio)),'',$queue);
}
function getMessages($queue)
{
    global $connection,$channel;
    $connection=new AMQPStreamConnection(RABBITMQ_SERVER,RABBITMQ_PORT,RABBITMQ_USERNAME,RABBITMQ_PASSWORD);
    $channel=$connection->channel();
    $channel->queue_declare($queue,true,false,false,false);
    $callback=function($msg)
    {
        if(handleMessage(json_decode($msg->body,true)))
        {
            $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
        }
        else
        {
            $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag'],false,true);
        }
    };
    $channel->basic_qos(null,1,null);
    $channel->basic_consume($queue,'',false,false,false,false,$callback);
    while(count($channel->callbacks))
    {
        try{$channel->wait();}
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work if you use the timeout parameter to $channel->wait();

Comment: I changed $channel->wait(); to $channel->wait(null,false,60);  It worked, but its worth noting that it didn't remain in the while(count($channel->callbacks)) loop, it exited the getmessage function closed the connection and restarted the whole connection a second later when getmessages runs in the top while loop.   I guess it works even though there's lots of reconnection overhead...

Answer (score 0):

The zero timeout is not working properly, as you said the broker may close connection and PHP consumer doesn't spot it.

The solution would be to use no zero receive timeout. Make sure connection timeout is bigger than receive one.

Here's an example based on [AMQP Interop](https://github.com/queue-interop/queue-interop#amqp-interop):

Install the AMQP Interop compatible transport, for example:

```
composer require enqueue/amqp-bunny
```

The code does same things as your with explicitly set timeouts:

```
<?php
use Enqueue\AmqpBunny\AmqpConnectionFactory;
use Interop\Amqp\AmqpConsumer;
use Interop\Amqp\AmqpMessage;
use Interop\Amqp\AmqpQueue;

$context = (new AmqpConnectionFactory(sprintf(
    'amqp://%s:%s@%s:%s/%2f?connection_timeout=600', // 10 min
    RABBITMQ_USERNAME,RABBITMQ_PASSWORD, RABBITMQ_SERVER, RABBITMQ_PORT
)))->createContext();

$context->setQos(null,1,null);

//sendMessage

$queue = $context->createQueue("transcode2");
$queue->addFlag(AmqpQueue::FLAG_PASSIVE);
$context->declareQueue($queue);

$message = $context->createMessage(json_encode($msg));
$message->setPriority($prio);

$producer = $context->createProducer();
$producer->send($queue, $message);

// getMessages

$consumer = $context->createConsumer($queue);
$context->subscribe($consumer, function(AmqpMessage $message, AmqpConsumer $consumer) {
    if(handleMessage(json_decode($message->getBody(), true))) {
        $consumer->acknowledge($message);
    } else {
        $consumer->reject($message);
    }

    return true;
});

$receiveTimeout = 5000; // 5 seconds, should be lesser than connection_timeout which is 600 seconds now.

$context->consume($receiveTimeout);
```